# Add image sensor driver to linux kernel

Tags: module, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver, kernel-module

I am working on a project that is using [Leopardboard DM368](http://shop.leopardimaging.com/product.sc?productId=30) interfacing with [LI-M024DUAL](https://www.leopardimaging.com/LI-M024-DUAL.html) camera board for stereo vision. The camera uses Aptina's MT09M024 as its image sensor. 
After spending a lot of time on the web searching for appropriate drivers I asked the OEM to provide me some support. They provided me with the driver source files. The problem is I am not able to include them to the kernel. 
I also looked up for the method to build modules and am fairly comfortable with it. But with the current driver I have a bunch of *.c files that use non-existent header files (I am not able to find these linux header files in the /linux directory).

Now my question is if I have the source code for an image sensor driver and want to build it, what is the general procedure followed for the same.

Any help in this regard would be welcome.

-Kartik

Comment: The header files you are refering here, are they standard linux kernel header files or vendor specific? If they are vendor specific, you should get them from vendor (OR from where you got the sources ie. OEM). And if they are Linux Kernel headers they should be there in include/ directory of you kernel. Please grep the kernel source for them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the header files are vendor specific because I cannot find them in the linux header folder. I guess now I need to contact the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to build you module:
1. Statically linking to kernel image (inbuilt)
2. Creating dynamically loadable Modules

1. Statically linking to kernel image (inbuilt)
   For this you must find a appropriate place in kernel folder (somewhere in drivers/) to copy your .c files. copy them there. Edit Kconfig and Makefiles refering to other kernel drivers. and enable the support using menuconfig. Compile.
2. Creating dynamically loadable Modules

You can built without copying them to Kernel source. Just create a Makefile and place rules in Makefile to compile your module. Here you must link your module to your kernel by providing the kernel source path.

For more google should help.